# Fps unity on android 30 and 45 only

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d, frame-rate

My project has this problem on my PC 1000 FPS And on mobile 30 and 45 Tris 300k Drawcall 200 V-Sync = 0 ,30 and 44 FPS V-Sync = 2 ,30 and 45 fps Why? I use target frame but this can not increase FPS Please help me

Comment: probably because the graphics card on your pc is 1000 better than that of a tablet or mobile phone

Comment: No , i optimized my project crazily but fps on phones between 30 & 45. Im very tired . Help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

200 draw calls are too much for a mobile app. You might have to reduce it. For mobile devices numbers should be 40 to 60 and for latest mobile devices you can go up-to 120 to 160

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BwrGj-HvKb4R7HOKGPJV5QTakweYwBHp/view?usp=sharing

Please See that .

Comment: how to solve that   ???????

Comment: Are you using real time lighting??

Comment: Also you can increase performance by combining meshes and using one material for whole object using texture mappings.

Comment: I baked lights lightmap

Comment: How to combine mesh & textures in unity?

Comment: you can't do it in unity as I know. What you can do is import the assets to blender and do it there

Comment: Quality increase with this way